# How to schedule task to run everyday, if I don't know when the pc will be turned on?

Tags: linux, cron, scheduling

So, I could use the `crontab` command, with:

```
23 0 * ...
```

but at `23:00` my laptop can be turned off, or hibernated. In that case I want a command to be executed as soon as it will be possible. How can I do that?

Comment: have a look at anacron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@reboot` in addition to your timing (if your crond supports it):

```
@reboot command
23 0 * * * command
```

The obvious caveat is that if you boot your computer at 22:59 the command will run twice in very short order. [Make sure the command can be run twice at the same time](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_make_sure_only_one_copy_of_my_script_can_run_at_a_time.3F) without one process stomping on the other.

Comment: It helps if laptop was turned off, but usually it is hibernated or suspended.

Comment: Can you add that information to the original question, or (even better) create a separate question for detecting waking from hibernation or suspension? I suspect that's a very different can of beans...

Comment: I thought that there is standard mechanism, to detect, if command wasn't executed, something like just a flag --yes_execute_it_if_you_didn't, so I don't have to care about all the cases, why command wasn't executed.